How to unmount hard drive from windows and mount to ubuntu in dual boot gaming tower?
I have Windows 11 and Ubunutu 24.04 installed in dual boot configuration. I have a 512g SSD for the OSs. There's a 2T hard drive attached to windows. I use Ubuntu everyday, and mostly only use Windows for occasional gaming; there's only games on the HDD. I've learned that games on Steam run on Ubuntu now. I want to detach the HDD from Windows and attach it to Ubuntu. I don't care if the HDD gets erased in the process. Though I'd prefer not if possible.
How do I do this?

As long as you have "Fast Startup" turned off, the HDD should be unmounted when you shut down Windows and boot Ubuntu. See How to automount NTFS partitions? for how to automatically mount your NTFS HDD in Ubuntu.

You're right. It's 24.04. This one. https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop#:~:text=Ubuntu%2024.04.1%20LTS,12%20years%20with%20Ubuntu%20Pro.

Don't I need to remove the HDD from inside Windows first? I can see the HDD from disks in Linux. What if I just reformat and mount the HDD from there? Does it matter if I use disks or gparted?

There is nothing to remove from inside Windows. If you don't care about the files and folders in your HDD you can reformat the HDD using ext4 file system used by Ubuntu. If you do that you will lose all your data, and Windows will not be able to recognize the HDD. It does not matter if you use Disks or Gparted as long as you don't erase your SSD by mistake.

See Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Share files between OS if you want to share your files between Windows and Ubuntu.

From what I can tell, only a minor portion of Steam games will run on

From what I can tell, only a portion of Steam games will run on a Linux system.  You might confirm that your particular games are compatible before erasing your entire HDD.  Perhaps you could partition your HDD and allocate some for Ubuntu but keep some for Windows with any games that aren't compatible yet.  https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-play-windows-games-on-linux/  https://www.protondb.com/

Do you have sources on linux gaming? I really don't like windows and for 8 years use ubuntu on everything, and only the dual boot for games or if a streaming service won't run on linux. I didn't realize that gaming is starting to come to linux and would probably totally delete windows in such a case. But as with ubunutu, I find new releases take a really long time to work out the bugs, so probably won't totally switch yet.
